# R:Extract duplicate data in two separate columns with variable column lengths

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a matrix I want to extract only the information that is duplicated in the first two columns, like the example below

---

```
 Var1 Var2 value
  b    a    100
  e    b     20
  g    c     40
       d     10
       e      5
       f    100
       g     25
```

the new data frame should look like this:

```
Var1 Var2 value
  b    b    20
  e    e     5
  g    g    25
```

---

So I want to get the information according to the second column(Var2) whose number is repeated in the first column(Var1).

Comment: Can you provide a `dput` of your data?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `intersect` to get common values between `Var1` and `Var2` and use it to get corresponding `value` from the dataframe.

```
vals <- intersect(df$Var1, df$Var2)
data.frame(Var1 = vals, Var2 = vals, Var3 = df$value[df$Var2 %in% vals])
#Or with match
#data.frame(Var1 = vals, Var2 = vals, Var3 = df$value[match(vals, df$Var2)])

#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    b    b   20
#2    e    e    5
#3    g    g   25
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = c("", "b", "e", "g"), class = "factor"), 
Var2 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), 
class = "factor"), value = c(100L, 20L, 40L, 10L, 5L, 100L, 25L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```